# How do you pass additional parameters to an event listener in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass additional parameters to my onChange handler, this is what the react component looks like

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

      handleFormChange(part, event) {
           console.log(event.target.value, part)
          }

      render() {
                 return (
                            <Row>
                                <Col>
                                    <Form.Label>Label</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control size="sm" type="text" placeholder="Label"
                                                  className="transparent" onChange={(event) => this.handleFormChange.bind('label', event)}/>
                                </Col>
      )

   }

}
```

But it doesn't seem like my event listener is doing anything. I can type onto it and I see no messages showing up in the console. What's the correct way to do this?

If I change it so that it's just `onChange={this.handleFormChange}` then it works but then I can't pass any additional parameters.

Comment: I don't think `bind` does what you think it does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind. `handleFormChange` doesn't use `this` so you don't need to `bind` it anyway.

Comment: I removed the part where I update the state in handleFormChange, but I do need `this` accessible in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind` returns a new function, it doesn't call it. So your event handler just creates a function and does nothing with it.

You can simply call `this.handleFormChange` from your event handler *or* use `.bind` to create the event handler:

```
onChange={(event) => this.handleFormChange('label', event)}
// or (the first argument is assigned to `this`, not the first parameter)
onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this, 'label')}
```

Comment: Ah, understood, would binding this event listener to (null, 'label') give it access to `this`? I have another call in the constructor that does this ` this.handleFormChange = this.handleFormChange.bind(this);`